# Angular URL Routing to Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm experiencing some difficulty getting my Angularjs to connect with my Laravel backend. I usually use RESTful controllers, but I just couldn't figure out how to get the show function to accept two parameters: a start date and an end date. Since it's a small project and only needs to retrieve information from a database and show it(based off a range of dates), I decided to forgo the controllers completely and just run the function inside my routes as shown below:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
Route::get('data/{startdate}/{enddate}', function($startdate, $enddate)
{
    return 'So you want the data from ' . $startdate . ' to ' . $enddate;
});
// Route::get('/data/{startdate}/{enddate}', 'WeatherdataController@show');
// Route::resource('data', 'WeatherdataController');
});
```

It works, insomuch as, when I hardcode the startdate and the enddate in the URL it returns the statement. So far so good. But I can't get my Angular front end to submit the http request. Here's my form:

```
<form method="GET" data-ng-controller="formController">
    Start Date:
    <input type="date" name="startdate" min="2001-01-12" data-ng-model="formInfo.startDate"   required> <span>--------></span>
    End Date:
    <input type="date" name="enddate" max="2014-12-08" data-ng-model="formInfo.endDate" required>

    <button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitRange()">Get Data</button>

</form>
```

And then this is my function:

```
function formController($scope, $http){
    $scope.formInfo = {};
    $scope.submitRange = function(){
        if ($scope.formInfo.endDate < $scope.formInfo.startDate) 
        {
            $('.error').append("<p>End Date cannot be earlier than Start Date.</p>");
        }

        $http.get("http://weatherdata.loc/api/v1/data/" + $scope.formInfo.startDate + "/" + $scope.formInfo.endDate )

    }
}
```

How do I get it to direct to that URL?

Comment: Typically, you don't. `$http.get(url).then(function(data){ console.log(data); /* do something useful with data */ });`

Comment: The call to `$http` returns a `promise` with `success` and `error` messages: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http